# https on google cloud works intermittently

Tags: google-app-engine, https, google-cloud-platform

Im using HTTPS provided by Google Cloud with an App Engine project.

And https://example.com works intermittently.

Many a times I see the error unable to connect.

But https://example.appspot.com will be working.

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Maybe your DNS provider is flakey?

Comment: There may be many reasons, including incorrect DNS configuration, connectivity issues, problems with your app itself, etc. You need to do more debugging. Do you see the requests in your app's logs (i.e. do they even reach your app)?